# How to create multiple dashboards in OMS?

Tags: azure, oms

I keep on reading hints that there should be a way to create multiple dashboards in OMS (maybe even with different user access rights), but I really can't find how to add them.
All I see is the designer to add, adjust und remove tiles from the one default dashboard.

Can someone clarify if it's indeed possible to create multiple dashboards and if yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible reason why you may not be getting that option.

*If your workspace has been upgraded to the new Log Analytics query language, then you cannot create new dashboards or edit existing dashboards.*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-dashboards

Comment: Thanks. Missed that part of the documentation.
Do you know if this feature will come back in the future?

Comment: I just looked at that part - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-log-search-upgrade - and looks like they are rolling it out gradually. If I know how Microsoft usually does these things, once it becomes available to everyone, you should be able to get it. Until, then, if you are the admin, you can roll back the upgrade.